# how to implement this Integrate[x^n E^(x - 1), {x, 0, 1}] in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, helper, matlab-guide, integral

hi I've search and read but  I couldn't solve this one in matlab.
please help me out to solve this problem 
integral_0^1 x^n e^(x-1) dx

Comment: first of all, you should show your effort so far. second, on SO latex syntax is not supported. third, `n` stays variable or not? You should clarify your question. It's easy to figure it out, but you should sort it in a clearer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can use different approaches to calculate the required integral:

1) **Symbolic Toolbox** --> I'd go for this one because of considerations on `n`

```
syms x n;

f = x.^n.*exp( x - 1 );

int(f,0,1)
```

2) `quad`, `integral` functions

```
g = @(n) (integral(@(x) x.^n.*exp(x-1),0,1));
g = @(n) (quad(@(x) x.^n.*exp(x-1),0,1));
```

Then you can evaluate the result depending on `n`.

3) `trapz` function

```
x = 0:.001:1;
y = x.^n.*exp( x - 1 );
trapz(x,y)
```

But, in this specific case, the calculation of the integral is driven by the exponent `n`.

Since I suppose and assume that you know how the integral of 'x.^n' behaves for different `n`, I will skip the discussion.

Comment: thank you ,I just didn't know the syms.thank again